# Error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string When using where function

Tags: laravel

i want to remove some post that have specific restrict value
the posts are 2 type (artists and songs) , songs belong artists

i get the songs of artist by below code but when i use where function to remove some songs its not working ang got error

**Error** :

> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

My Code

```
$rel = collect([]);
foreach ($post->artists as $artist) {
   $artist_posts = $artist->getPosts->where(function ($query) {
     $query->whereNotIn('restrict', ['res1'])->orWhereNull('restrict');                  
   })->sortbydesc('id');
   $rel = $rel->concat($artist_posts->where('type', $type));
}
$col = $rel->unique('id');
```

Post.php (model)

```
...
public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'artists_posts', 'artist_id', 'post_id')->with('artists');
    }
 ...
```

Comment: what is `$type`?  also why are you passing a closure to `where` ... that is `Collection@where` not a Query Builder `where`

Comment: I am assuming that relationship method you are showing is on `Artist` not `Post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a Closure to the `where` method of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. That is not a Query Builder you are calling `where` on, it is a Collection.

```
/**
 * Filter items by the given key value pair.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $operator
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return static
 */
public function where($key, $operator = null, $value = null)
```

If you wanted to call `where` on a Query Builder to do a database query you would have to use the actual relationship method not the dynamic property:

```
 $artist_posts = $artist->getPosts()->where(function ($query) {
                                  ^^
```

Then you would have to adjust `sortbydesc` to `orderByDesc(...)` and you would have to call `get` on the Builder to get the Collection of results.